# C pointer to IntPtr

Tags: c#, c

I want to call a function of C dll from C# code. Function defined as SendData(S_DATA). S_DATA is structure which have a Pbyte data(pointer to byte) as below

```
struct S_DATA { ushort field1, ulong field2, pbyte pdata }:
```

In C# I am calling this function as

```
 [DllImport("C_Function.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = 
        CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "SendData")]
                static extern ushort SendData(S_DATA data);
        byte [] data_To_Send = new byte[20];
S_DATA data = new S_DATA();
data.field1 = 1;
data.field2 = 2;
data.pdata = new IntPtr();
data.pdata = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data_To_Send.Length);         
Marshal.Copy(data_To_Send, 0, data.pdata, data_To_Send.Length);
SendData (data);//--> this line it give me error as below
```

> Exception thrown at 0x7528CA42 in XXX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEMessageException at memory location 0x0A5CF260.

its not clear for me how to send a byte array from C# in the PByte variable of c function parameter.
basically I have byte array with data that I need to send to the c function call

Comment: I realize my C# is rusty as hell, but thank God for garbage collection, because this: `data.pdata = new IntPtr();` followed immediately by: `data.pdata = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data_To_Send.Length);` would be a recipe for a memory leak in any other non-GC language. Just sayin. That said, are you *certain* the calling convention of your C code is cdecl?

Comment: There are many things that could go wrong with PInvoke. Calling convention and struct alignment might be culprit here. I also suspect that sending byte data usually requires the data length to be sent, but it is missing here. You should refer to DLL documentation in details or just post it here.

Comment: How does the C function know how big the buffer is? Side note: You are missing `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` which should be in a `finally`.

Comment: Yes I am using calling convention cdecl.

Comment: There will be a field in the S_DATA struct which will have buffer size, thanks yes we need to add Marshal.FreeHGlobal

Comment: one question may be little silly one, if we Free memory from C#, still C might be using it then will it create problem ? or this memory was only for C# and then C will create it own memory for that byte pointer ?

Comment: Is it possible to send byte ref to the pointer in C function parameter, looks like whatever i try is failing. may be some other way if someone have tried then please let me know

Comment: is there any other way that i can send byte data to c pointer ?

Comment: You need to show us all this information, not make us guess. Where is this field? Who is allocating the memory and who is expected to free it? What is the C definition of the function and struct? You can easily pass a `byte[]` array as a pointer in a struct, but the C code has to know how big it is.